# Keyboard issue in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, 17.10

Some of keys of keyboard stopped working in ubuntu 17.10. Shift stopped with some of keys like t , angular brackets, m. 
I have been using ubuntu from 2 years. I haven't faced this issue. Please help me

Comment: i have used live boot of all ubuntu flavours. I am facing same issue.

Comment: Can you try using another keyboard, like a USB keyboard?

Comment: i am using ubuntu in laptop. I installed xkeycaps and tried different keyboard layout.It didn't worked.

Comment: Most laptops will recognize a USB keyboard and work with that - can you check with friends and associates to see if you can borrow one?  I suspect that the keyboard on your laptop has gone bad, or become partially disconnected.

Comment: i will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`
Reboot

Try
 `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`
Reboot

You can use the 'on screen keyboard' to help you get there.

Ref:[Ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2363499)